# Mass forward usermailbox emails to mailcontacts with same name. Need powershell command to do so

Tags: exchange, powershell, exchange-2007, mail-forwarding

I have 2 OU's of users that each have a mail contact with the same name in a seperate single OU.  So Jane Doe would be in Staff\OU1 with jdoe@contoso.com email.  Mike Doe would be in Staff\OU2 with mdoe@contoso.com.  Then in the OU Contacts\Staff they would each have a contact of their names with email address of username@contoso.com.test-google-a.com.  I need to forward all users emails in OU1 and OU2 to their contacts in the contacts\staff OU.  Also i need mail to go to their mailbox AND the contact email.  Is there a syntax in powershell that would do this for me?

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a one time operation or set up mail forwarding for future emails?

Comment: It will be a one time operation that gets repeated.  User's are added in bulk here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are working with Exchange mailboxes (it's not terribly clear in your question) [Set-Mailbox](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb123981(v=EXCHG.150).aspx) is your best friend.

You're going to need a for-each loop to retrieve the user's attributes and properly set the destination SMTP address.  If you have a whole OU of users to apply changes to, use something like:

```
Get-Mailbox -OrganizationalUnit <OU> | % {Set-Mailbox -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ForwardingSMTPAddress "($_.Alias)@otherdomain.com"}
```

IMO the first example in the Set-Mailbox page linked is close to what you are trying to do.

Frankly you should not need the contacts, as it's just something else to manage in this case.  However, I might not be parsing your question correctly.  If you need to manage contacts, this would be `Get-MailUser` instead of `Get-Mailbox`. You can still specify `-OrganizationalUnit` with `Get-MailUser`, so you can test that out first.

Instead of `ForwardingSMTPAddress` property, you would want to specify the property `ExternalEmailAddress` on `Set-MailUser`

Comment: Sorry, yes it's exchange 2007.  The organization is in the process of migrating to google apps.  The manager of the project has said that they need their email to forward to the .test-google-a.com for the mail to route to google. The local exchange needs to stay in place right now as well.  The command you gave me does not need the actual contacts to be created then correct?  This just adds a forwarding address right to their domain mailbox? In exchange management console we couldn't specify an address so we had to use a mail contact.   This command will get around that though?  Thanks

Comment: Also thank you for the help.  I am an IT consultant for this client so i have forwarded your solution to the IT director here as I'm not sure if the contacts were required to be used for any other reason.  I will mark as an answer once i get approval from him.

Comment: This should bypass the need for mail contacts in your directory.  If you're setting up any Directory Sync with Google, there might need to be contacts there to facilitate communication back to Exchange.  I would think this would be a scenario where you sync your Contacts OU to Google, and not your Users (maybe?).

Comment: That may be why it was done like that then.  The IT director had said there was a command he could run to set the forwarding to the contacts in bulk, but he wasn't able to find it again.  Would there be a command to mass deploy the forwarding rules to the actual mail contacts instead of just specifying the SMTP address?

Comment: @Brian, I believe this would be `Get-MailUser` instead of `Get-Mailbox`.  You can still specify `-OrganizationalUnit` with `Get-MailUser`, so you can test that out first.  Instead of `ForwardingSMTPAddress`, you would want to specify the property `ExternalEmailAddress` on `Get-MailUser`

Comment: So i used the following  Get-Mailuser -OrganizationalUnit "OU" | % {Set-Mailuser -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true -ExternalEmailAddress "($_.Alias)@contoso.org.test-google-a.com"} But I dont think it was right.  Alias isn't part of a mail contact right?  Is there something else i should be putting there?

Comment: I tried the original command to forward to SMTP address and it didnt work.  I get an error that ForwardingSMTPaddress is an unknown parameter.  I think exchange 2007 can only forward to a mail contact.

Comment: Good Catch, Alias is NOT a part of MailUser.  if you do `Get-MailUser -Identity (pick one) | FL` you will get all properties.  Hopefully you can grab one that will allow you to use a single value.

Comment: So i was able to get this working with the following command.  Import-Csv c:\faculty.csv | % {Set-Mailbox $_.MbxAlias -ForwardingAddress $_.ContactAlias -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true}  I exported the mailbox list and MbxAlias is the mailbox alias.  I edited the list to combine first and last name to firstlast with no space and named the column ContactAlias.  Alias IS part of the mail contact but it is the full firstlast name.  Thanks again for the help.  I really appreciate it.